# How can I delete a row when a date I have set in the future equals today?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have built my company a program that'll send our clients email reminders for five years after we've built their church. I made the table of contact information in SQL so that I can use it as dynamic content in Microsoft Flow. I've been figuring out the language alright and I have my table built. I have the id column, the name of the Church, their email address, the date the project was completed, and the date of removal (I set this to be the date of completion + 5 years). I'd really like for the church's row to delete after five years, when the date_of_removal equals the current_date so that they don't get our emails for the rest of time.

I've tried writing it different ways and they all resembled these:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts
    DROP ROW * WHERE date_of_removal<=CURRENT_DATE;
```

and:

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE date_of_removal <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

(it says incorrect syntax near current_date)

Please let me know what you think or if you need more information. All of your suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GETDATE()`:

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE date_of_removal <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

SQL Server supports `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but not `CURRENT_DATE`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! It's good to know that SQL Server doesn't support CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using Microsoft flow, so chances are you're using SQL Server. Have you tried

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE date_of_removal <= GETDATE();
```